# use tools:overrideLibrary="org.springframework.android.rest.test" to force usage

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, google-api

I got the following error message:

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':Project1:processBetaDebugManifest'.
 Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 17 declared in library /Users/motianim/Project/mobile-ws/src/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/src/Projecct/unspecified/AndroidManifest.xml
 Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.springframework.android.rest.test" to force usage
```

I tried following things to solve the issue:

- installed google apis 17.
- re-installed the android studio and the re-imported the project.
- reboot of complete system.

I'm still having the problem.

Comment: Now, I am able to solve this problem by adding the following code to build.gradle file
-
defaultConfig {

        versionCode computeVersionNumber()

        versionName getFullVersion() + "_" + versionCode

        minSdkVersion 17

        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

Comment: Can you also post the code for computeVersionNumber() and getFullVersion()