# tools:overrideLibrary is not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to override the minSDK of a library I'm using in my gradle file. Following is the error message

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 13 declared in library [com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2] C:\Users\{User_Name}\{App_Name}\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.intuit.sdp\sdp-android\1.0.2\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.intuit.sdp" to force usage
```

A quick google told me to use overrideLibrary in Mainfest. so I add the following lines in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    tools:overrideLibrary="com.intuit.sdp" />
```

I then clean and rebuild the project but it's still showing me the exact same error as before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108027/use-toolsoverridelibrary-org-springframework-android-rest-test-to-force-usage

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to google on how to fix it all day! :D

Comment: @Vincent_Paing  am in the same problem. tring to use UIAutomator while my minimium sdk is 15 and it requires 18. how did you solve your problem?

Comment: @gikarasojokinene if you haven't solved this problem yet, here is the Stack Overflow Answer that fixed it for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/33753330/3456841

Comment: @Ethan  yeah, that answer also helped me solve my problem. you can see my comments in it. good day :)

Comment: It might be this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230777 ("build tools: processDebugManifest step fails or not depending on ordering of project dependencies")

In reported case reordering dependencies worked.