# How to use tools:overrideLibrary with multiple libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to create an Android project that is compatible to e.g. API level 4 but would still like to test it with UiAutomator that requires API level 18 on newer devices. So the app would also run on old devices but the automatic tests would be performed on new devices.

Therefore I have created a new project with Android Studio and added the UiAutomator test libraries:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
}
```

When compiling it I get the error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 4 cannot be smaller than version 8 declared in library [com.android.support.test:runner:0.3] /Users/dom/Entwicklung/MacBookPro/git/GradleTest/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support.test/runner/0.3/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test" to force usage
```

Adding

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test"/>
```

to the AndroidManifest.xml causes another error to occur:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 4 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1] /Users/dom/Entwicklung/MacBookPro/git/GradleTest/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage
```

Changing it to

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test, android.support.v7.appcompat"/>
```

causes the first error again:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 4 cannot be smaller than version 8 declared in library [com.android.support.test:runner:0.3] /Users/dom/Entwicklung/MacBookPro/git/GradleTest/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support.test/runner/0.3/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test" to force usage
```

I am using the latest Android Studio and build tools. The gradle command that Android Studio uses to build the app is

```
Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
```

so the problem can be reproduced e.g. with

```
gradle :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources
```

What is the correct syntax to specify multiple libraries in tools:overrideLibrary ? I have read that a comma and a space would be correct, but it doesn't seem to work. I have read a lot about it here on StackOverflow and elsewhere but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution so far (aside from commenting out the tests).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I have found out that the solution is to create a **second** AndroidManifest.xml, just for the tests. It has to be saved **into the tests directory** and needs to contain only the overrideLibrary statement:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="${applicationId}">
    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.app, android.support.test, android.support.test.rule, android.support.test.espresso, android.support.test.espresso.idling, android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>
</manifest>
```

If you are using a different directory for your tasks, you can specify it this way in your gradle file:

```
androidTest.setRoot('src_test_uiautomator')
```

The AndroidManifest.xml file has to be in the root of that directory, the test sources in the "java" subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks, it works! It's so stupid that Google didn't bother to document this problem...

Comment: setting the gradle file like ```androidTest {
   setRoot('src/main/androidTest/')
   java.srcDirs = ['src/main/androidTest/java/']
  }``` made this all work for me.

Comment: @ericharlow am tring to use your solution but am getting error in my app.gradle **Gradle DSL method not found: 'androidTest()'** i have tried to use `apply plugin: 'java'` but still getting the same error when i sync. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: my guess is you are putting the androidTest{} in the wrong location of your build.gradle. it needs to be nested under your ```android{ sourceSets{androidTest{}}}```

Comment: @ericharlow    you were right. i never knew it was supposed to be there. it finally worked. kudos for that boss.

Answer (score 27):

According to [official doc](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/manifest-merge.html)(section Merge conflict marker for imported libraries), it should be.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.android.example.app"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   ...
   <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="2"
             tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2"/>
```

where `com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2` are the packages declared in the AndroidManifes inside the libraries.

Comment: Yes, I have read these docs and I have tried to add minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion now but it doesn't make a difference :-(

<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" android:minSdkVersion="4"
        tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test, android.support.v7.appcompat"/>

Additionally these values are taken from the build.gradle anyway. As far as I can see I have tried it exactly as in your example and in another example that I have found here on StackOverflow. I cannot find out what is wrong. It is an empty project to which I have added only the test library dependencies.

Comment: @Dominique it doesn't resolve your issue, but if it is a new project, why are you using minSdk=4. With minSdk=8 you will cover 100% of the current android distribution. https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: minSdk=8 does not help because then the library "android.support.test.uiautomator.v18" requires minSdk=18. Additionally the real project is not a new project. But to ensure that there is a real problem I reproduced the problem with a new, empty project. And I can reproduce it by just adding the four androidTestCompile dependency lines to a new Android Studio project with minSdk=7 or minSdk=8.

Comment: @Dominique did you manage to solve this issue? I'm also implementing uiAutomator and running into the same issue. tools:overrideLibrary doesn't seem to get picked up by android studio.

Comment: @Mixx No, unfortunately no one seems to know a solution. Currently I am changing the gradle build file manually to either work for the tests or to compile the app. My idea was to download the sources of Android's gradle extension and look why overrideLibrary does not correctly work. But first I had to download the complete Android source code (which took a long time) and then the sources were in a strange format so that I didn't fine the sources of the gradle extension yet :-(

Comment: @Mixx I have found the reason and a solution, please see my answer below.